# Scala Expression of Type Unit doesn't confirm to type String

Tags: scala, error-handling, try-catch

```
try{
    throwsException();
} catch {
    case e: IOException => println("IO Exception");
} finally {
    println("this code is always executed");
}
```

In the 

`catch`
section, it always pops "Expression of Type Unit doesn't confirm to type String" error.

Comment: there's probably some missing context here - looks like this code is the body of a function/block that returns `String`, and in case of an exception it doesn't - can you please add the code encapsulating this fragment?

Comment: probably u can try to do something like this catch{ case e:IOException => e.getMessage} . Basically ur function is expecting String but you are returning nothing

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this code is part of a larger block which is supposed to evaluate as a `String`. For example we can consider following,

```
def getStringResult(): String = {
  try{
    throwsException();
  } catch {
    case e: IOException => println("IO Exception");
  } finally {
   println("this code is always executed");
  }
}
```

Now, you can see that in case of exception you are providing `{ case e: IOException => println("IO Exception") }` which is a partial function of type `IOException => Unit`. And this is leading to type mismatch.

You can solve this problem like following,

```
def getStringResult(): String = {
  try{
    throwsException();
  } catch {
    case e: IOException => "IOException String"
  }
}
```

Or you can do a more Scala-like aproach,

```
def getStringResult(): String = {
  val resultTry = Try(throwsException())
  // resultTry will be of type Try[String]

  resultTry.getOrElse("String in case of exception")
}
```